# MVC folder structure - structure primarily by business module rather than M/V/C?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, directory-structure

I am designing a complex web based business solution. My Domain, Reports and Processes projects are structured around business modules (3-4 levels deep) eg.:

```
\Franchises
   \Regionals
      \Billing
         \Monthly
         \...
         \...
      \...
      \...
   \...
   \...
\...
\...
```

The traditional MVC folder structure sticks out line a sore thumb, with max 2 levels deep. Therefore I plan to implement this structure instead:

```
\Franchises\Regionals\Billing\Monthly\RegionalMonthlyBillingController.cs
\Franchises\Regionals\Billing\Monthly\Views\...
\Franchises\Regionals\Billing\Monthly\ViewModels\...

\Franchises\Divisionals\Allocation\DivisionalAllocationController.cs
\Franchises\Divisionals\Allocation\Views\...
\Franchises\Divisionals\Allocation\ViewModels\...
...
```

Note that our domain models are held in Domain, and the WebUI need only contain ViewModels.

Aside from the problem of customizing the MVC routing/mapping, can you see any problems with this approach?

Given there will be many Views folders, could there be a performance concern with MVC having to search 500+ folders to find the relevant view?

Comment: I think you can handle with asp.net MVC areas although you can put the controllers or areas in separate them with namespace and then create your own custom routing, but try to use portable areas in such a big application to better management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aside from the problem of customizing the MVC routing/mapping, can you
>   see any problems with this approach?

Might lead to some pretty large project and it might be difficult to navigate for a newcomer. You could consider externalizing some of the logic in separate assemblies to avoid having a single monolith application. Consider ASP.NET MVC Areas.

> Given there will be many Views folders, could there be a performance
>   concern with MVC having to search 500+ folders to find the relevant
>   view?

No, when running in release mode (debug="false"), ASP.NET MVC caches the location of the views and the lookup is pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's the same number of views & controllers either way, just whether a whole bunch of only vaguely related ones get lumped in together, or can be organized consistently with the other tiers.